# Is there a way to select different rows each time avoiding ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with approximately 100 million rows (TABLE_A), I need to select 6 millons **different** rows each query, once the entire table is selected, the process ends. TABLE_A does not have index or primary key, and ORDER BY is very expensive in terms of time, also I don't need any order here, just different rows. I have tried to order using ROWID, according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm),

> They are the fastest way to access a single row.

This query works but takes about 5 minutes (I would like to avoid this order by)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY ROWID
OFFSET 6000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6000000 ROWS ONLY;
```

This query works faster but has no sense since ROWNUM, according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255)

> returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row
> from a table

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY ROWNUM asc
OFFSET 6000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6000000 ROWS ONLY;
```

As expected, same query returns different results each time.

This query seems to be conceptually better.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE ROWID >= 6000000 AND ROWID <12000000;
```

But it can't be done in this way, ROWID (UROWID Datatype) has values like `AAAZIUAHWAAC6XcAAI`

So, Is there a way to select different rows avoiding order? and just call the rows using some kind of internal ID, maybe a direction in the storage or maybe a default order. The whole approach was likely wrong, so I'm open to radical changes.

I've also tried somethig like this

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
    WHERE dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) 
    BETWEEN 2049 AND 261281;
```

it's surprisingly fast but unfortunately a row could have more than one block number.

Comment: Different from what?  What do you do on day 17 when all the rows have run out?  What are some columns in the table?  Perhaps they can be used.  What if a row is updated?

Comment: We could assume that there is no updates, when all rows are selected nothing happen, the process ends. TABLE_A has 33 columns, there are VARCHAR2, NUMBER and DATE, but non of them are unique, there is a combination of 3 columns that we could find differences between rows.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: @jarlh That was my first approach, but it uses the dreaded ORDER BY

Comment: ORDER BY primary key shouldn't be bad, or?

Comment: There is no primary key

Comment: Maybe add an index if the table does not have any.

Comment: Can you open an explicit cursor and fetch the rows in batches?

Comment: I'm doing that, but it takes hours, I'm in fact splititig that process (cursor) to run parallel in 16 processes, but I need each process to select 6 different millons to run 6*16 millons at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, some things to look at:

1. DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE

If you are going through 100 million rows, the best place to process them is on the database itself. If your processing is done with PL/SQL, then dbms_parallel_execute can manage most of the parallelisation for you, and carve up the rows.

2. ROWID ranges

Even if you don't *process* the rows on the database, you can use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE to produce the rowid ranges for you.  Then use those start-end pairs as inputs to whatever app you are using to do the processing

3. simple MOD

Each instance of your app gets an ID from 0 to 'n-1' and each issues a query

```
select * 
from ( 
  select rownum r, m.* from my_table
)  
where mod(r,"n") = :x
```

where x is that app's ID.  If you already have a numeric sequence column of some sort that is reasonably distributed, you can substitute that in for the rownum

Comment: Thanks @Connor This is useful, I was trying to use `CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID`  I can't because is not IOT (Index Organized Table/s). I'm trying now using `CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL`,  it takes very long time to make the chunks, also It seems that I cant't select the chuncks size. Unfortunately I can't use  PL/SQL, at least I can't imagine how, because I need these querys to be run from a python script.

Comment: OK, if it is an IOT, then you can get the MIN and MAX values of the primary key with minimal cost by running 2 queries.  Then just divide (max-min)/16 to get your ranges.